# WKWebview: Handle the button click event from app

Tags: swift2, wkwebview

Can I handle the button click event of `WKWebView` from my app.

Simply I have opened a facebook login page in my `WKWebView`. Is it possible to handle the event of that login button from my app?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `navigationDelegate` of the `WKWebView` to listen to that action. The delegate method you should implement is:

Swift

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void)
{
    let request = navigationAction.request; // Inspect this request to see if it's from Facebook
    let policy = WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow or WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel depending if you want the request to continue firing or not
    decisionHandler( policy );
}
```

Objective-C

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
    NSURLRequest *request = navigationAction.request; // Inspect this request to see if it's from Facebook
    WKNavigationActionPolicy policy = WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow or WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel depending if you want the request to continue firing or not
    decisionHandler( policy );
}
```

Comment: Swift 2.its not working.I need a event of that login button.??? I have implemented this.
        func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
            print("webView:\(webView) decidePolicyForNavigationAction:\(navigationAction) decisionHandler:\(decisionHandler)")
         
            
            decisionHandler(.Allow)
        }